# Copy Data from Azure DWH TO Dynamics 365 in Azure

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory

it is possible to copy CRM data from Dynamics 365 to a DWH with the Azure Datafactory. But is it possible to, for example, create new Data in the Table that was copied from Dynamics 365 and copie that Table back to Dynamics 365?

Export: Dynamics to Blob to DWH 
then create new Data in Table in DWH
Import: DWH to Blob to Dynamics 365 (CRM)

Answer (score 0):

ADF does support upsetting data to Dynamics 365 CRM. 
Please try and let us know if any specific problem you hit.